# how to avoid crystallization of powdered sugar

Tags: storage-method, sugar

I have powdered white sugar and stored it in a glass bottle. I see the next day that the sugar had crystallized and i cant seem to take it out or anything. Tried to keep under sun. No result. i have no other go than to discard the whole bottle.

Comment: Can you post an image of it? Powdered sugar in the US (also called icing sugar) has cornstarch in it... which, as far as I know, keeps it from ever really hardening up. I've never had an issue with powdered sugar, myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you powdered it yourself, you should have added cornstarch, else it goes stone-hard quickly.

Second, you have to keep it away from moisture. The bottle would have to be closed tightly, and you have to use a perfectly dry bottle, not a just-washed one. If you live in tropical region or somewhere else with really high moisture, a bottle may not be a good container, try something wide mouthed from which you can break out the sugar if needed.

For the existing bottle, you might not need to discard it. Try soaking it in a larger water container overnight. With luck, it will dissolve the sugar enough to get it (partly?) out. The resulting sweet liquid can be boiled down to make simple syrup or caramel. You might need to boil it for a long time though, depending on the amount of water used.

Comment: I was not aware of cornstarch. it did go stone hard. let me buy it for next time.. thank you!